# Can not debug app in ios device with xamarin studio

Tags: ipad, debugging, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have developed an ipad app in xamarin studio(monotouch), suddenly I cannot debug this app in ios device(ipad) any more, but in ios simulator everything works fine.

From the "Build Output" I got following information, any ideas would be nice.

> error MT0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
>   System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/IPAD_GIT/Vendor12_IPad/bin/iPhone/Debug/Vendor12_IPad.app/MonoTouch.Dialog.PickerElement.dll.mdb
>     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean isAsync, Boolean anonymous) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess)
>     at Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolWriter.WriteSymbolFile (Guid guid) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Cecil.Mdb.MdbWriter.Dispose () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionWriter.TerminateModuleDefinition (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Cecil.StructureWriter.TerminateAssemblyDefinition (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition asm) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Accept (IReflectionStructureVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyFactory.WriteAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition asm, System.IO.BinaryWriter bw) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyFactory.SaveAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition asm, System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyFactory.SaveAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition asm, System.String file) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MTouch.SaveAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean symbols, System.String destination) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MTouch.Main2 (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MTouch.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "iOS Build"->"Linker Options"->"Linker behavior" I set the value from "Link SDK assemblies only" to "Link all assemblies", and problem solved. But I still didn't understand the difference and don't know if there will be other problems by changing this setting.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by some oddity in your mounted file system in /Volumes/BOOTCAMP

Try moving your code out of it.

Comment: I just changed the building option of my project and it worked!

Comment: In the "iOS Build"->"Linker Options"->"Linker behavior" I set the value from "Link SDK assemblies only" to "Link all assemblies", and problem solved. But I still didn't understand the difference and don't know if there will be other problems by changing this setting.